# Why does Firefox set a background color on the select arrow button when I set a custom border or background color?

Tags: css, firefox

A default select input looks like this in FF 37:

[image]

When I try to give it a different border color like this:

```
select { border: 1px solid silver; }
```

It results into this:

[image]

For some reason when you give a select input a different border it also adds a background and border to the arrow button.

A similar thing happens when I do the following:

```
select { background: transparent; }
```

It ends up like this:

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I just change the border or background of a select input without it changing the arrow down button?

[jsfiddle with example](https://jsfiddle.net/81L844p4/)

Comment: This is presumably due to how Windows Vista/7/8/10 handles rendering of select boxes.

Comment: @BoltClock Just tested it on Ubuntu and while the default style in Ubuntu is different the result is the same.

Comment: I guess different systems have two different visual states for select boxes (usually this is to distinguish a select from a combo box). I'm seeing a similar result in Safari on OS X as well now that I've tested. I know that Windows XP renders the arrow button in select boxes and combo boxes the same way.

Comment: @BoltClock find it a bit weird that if you just want to change one property like a border color the whole select box defaults to some basic version of itself. I did some research before asking but most results I found was how to completely get rid of the arrow button with `-moz-appearance: none`. That makes me think that people solve this by adding their own custom arrow down icon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To start with, styling form elements is extremely complicated and troublesome. Some progress has been made lately, but behaviour is inconsistent from browser to browser. The problem comes from the way browser have historically handled form elements (letting the OS decide the element appearance).

Now to your question: for some reason, whenever you modify FF default stylesheet, the browser applies a different style to the dropdown (this may be a bug, a bad implementation or planned behaviour, but it's clearly annoying).

One solution would be to get rid of all the "chrome" altogether, using a vendor property `-x-appearance: none`, like this:

```
select {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  padding-right: 25px;
  background: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCwALAJEAAAAAAP///xUVFf///yH5BAEAAAMALAAAAAALAAsAAAIPnI+py+0/hJzz0IruwjsVADs=);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 95% 42%;
}
```

Note that you have to re-apply the down arrow (I did this by inserting an image as a background, encoded in base64.) You can use any image of your liking.

The problem with this approach is that it doesn't work in IE: http://caniuse.com/#search=appearance

Here you have a Fiddle to test it: https://jsfiddle.net/81L844p4/4/

Hope it helps.

Comment: backgrounds properties can be concatenated into one like this:
`background: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhCwALAJEAAAAAAP///xUVFf///yH5BAEAAAMALAAAAAALAAsAAAIPnI+py+0/hJzz0IruwjsVADs=) no-repeat 95% 42%;`

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by Damian is not bad, but I prefered something what is easier to maintain. Basically, I also need to have a possibility to prepare one style, which I could change a color depending on theme, therefore png image (in base64) was not a good option.

This is how this can be done with SVG:

```
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;

    /* SVG background image */
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='%23FF0000'><polygon points='20,0 80,0 50,52'/></svg>");
    background-size: 12px;
    background-position-x: right;
    background-position-y: calc(100% - 10px);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I use scss to generate styles based on variables, so i wanted to use `$base-font-color` as a color of triangle. The problem was encoding.

Chrome can handle simple `.. fill='"+ $base-font-color +"' ..` in:

```
background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='"+ $base-font-color +"'><polygon points='20,0 80,0 50,52'/></svg>");
```

but firefox needed `%23`. That was a problem, bacause I store colors in variables as: `$base-font-color: #3e4f5e;` and not as a `$base-font-color: '3e4f5e'`. Solution was to [convert color to string](https://hugogiraudel.com/2014/01/27/casting-types-in-sass/) and use [string replacement](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/str-replace-function/) to replace '#' to '%23'

```
@function str-replace($string, $search, $replace: '') {
  $index: str-index($string, $search);

  @if $index {
    @return str-slice($string, 1, $index - 1) + $replace + str-replace(str-slice($string, $index + str-length($search)), $search, $replace);
  }

  @return $string;
}

@function to-string($value) {
  @return inspect($value);
}

select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;

    /* SVG background image */
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' fill='"+ str-replace(to-string($base-font-color), '#', '%23')  +"'><polygon points='20,0 80,0 50,52'/></svg>");
    background-size: 12px;
    background-position-x: right;
    background-position-y: calc(100% - 10px);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove this problem just set a border.

```
select {
     border:1px solid black;
    }
```