# change the color of the selectbox dropdown in mozilla

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have created a select box background color .In chrome dropdown appear with background color but in chrome appear in white color.I want to apply background color in mozilla dropdown as in chrome

```css
select{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<select>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
</select>
```

same dropdown is appear as white color in mozilla

Answer (score 0):

Similar question has been answered before. You need to set -moz-appearance as none. [Why does Firefox set a background color on the select arrow button when I set a custom border or background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512525/why-does-firefox-set-a-background-color-on-the-select-arrow-button-when-i-set-a)

```
select {
border: 1px solid silver;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
padding-right: 25px;
background-color: red
}
```