# CSS select box looks different on certain computers/browsers

Tags: html, css

A select box in html looks different on certain computers/browsers. On someone else his computer on google chrome the box looks like this, which should be standard:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/ee09fcdad5399d61fcd49373a3d63530.png]

but on my computer in google chrome it looks like this:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/46d8d4e0f17a9f2f1d512a1a6dd57080.png]

I already cleared my chrome browsing history. When I use Edge on my computer, it also shows the first image. How do I make it work on my computer for chrome?

This is the css of the select box:

```
.select2-container {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  width: auto !important;
}

.select2-container .select2-selection--single {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  height: 48px;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Follow my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29512525/why-does-firefox-set-a-background-color-on-the-select-arrow-button-when-i-set-a/72342942#72342942 of this link.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own design but you have to set the appearance to none in all web browsers then specify styles.

Replace the green box in the right side with down arrow icon. you can find some [here on icon8.com](https://icons8.com/icon/set/arrow/all)

Try this code:

```css
select {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/15/0f2') 95% no-repeat #fafafa;
}

select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Option1</option>
  <option>Option1</option>
  <option>Option1</option>
  <option>Option1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: But what if I want to keep the same style?

Comment: same computed style for each browser? then do nothing about the styles

Answer (score 0):

Each browser has different default styles. So a select box on chrome, may look different on firefox, as you have discoverred.

To fix this you need to reset the default styling.

Use a style-sheet like Normalize.css [Link](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)